# Why is QFuture not working asynchronously?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to see my GUI interface immediately and initialize the application on an asynchronous thread.

For this I am using `QFuture`.

My code:

```
// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // create config and credentials
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    LoginForm loginForm(config, credentials);

    int result = app.exec();


    return result;
}
```

Then in the login form I am using `QFuture`:

```
void initLauncher(const Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration &config, const Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials &credentials) {
    // slow function
}

LoginForm::LoginForm(const Aws::Client::ClientConfiguration &config, const Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials &credentials,
                     QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), awsConfig(config), awsCredentials(credentials) {

    ...
    QFuture<void> future = QtConcurrent::run([this, &config, &credentials]() {
        initLauncher(config, credentials);
    });
    QFutureWatcher<void> *watcher = new QFutureWatcher<void>(this);
    connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(initializationFinished()));
    // delete the watcher when finished too
    connect(watcher, SIGNAL(finished()), watcher, SLOT(deleteLater()));
    watcher->setFuture(future);

    // creating buttons 
    show();
```

Where `LoginForm` is the `QWidget` class.

**Problem** -- I see the GUI interface only after the `initLauncher()` function is done. How can I show the GUI interface before `initLauncher()`?

Comment: `[this, &config, &credentials]` - that is very scary to me, and would earn a - in code review.  You are taking references to reference arguments and having them persist over some unknown period of time while the future runs, very unclear lifetime semantics.

Comment: Is `show()` running before `initLauncher`?  Does `initLauncher` lock any data structures that would mess with `show`?  Is your thread pool configured reasonably?

Comment: I think that show() is running after initLauncher (I don't know how to fix it)
I didn't configure ThreadPool. What should I do?

Comment: first drop those `&` in lambda capture list to avoid UB in your application then retest this. I would not be surprised if `Yakk` nailed the problem.

Comment: `// creating buttons``show();` is suspicious.. `show()` is `setVisible(true)`